# Give $z\in C$: $|1+z|\geq \frac{1}{2}$ then $|1+z^{2}|\geq 1$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Given $$z\in C: |1+z|\geq \frac{1}{2}$$

then prove:  $$|1+z^{2}|\geq 1$$

Help me please, I can't prove that.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot prove this. For $z=i\,$ you have $|1+z| = |1+i| = \sqrt{2}\ge \tfrac{1}{2}\,,$ but obviously $|1+z^2|=|1-1| = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

$\hspace1in$[image]

The best we can say if $\left|z+1\right|\geq\frac{1}{2}$ is $\left|z^2-\frac{5}{4}\right|\geq 1$. In the figure, the purple circle is the unit circle, the yellow circle is the circle $\left|z+1\right|=\frac{1}{2}$, the green circle is the circle $\left|z-\frac{9}{4}\right|=1$ and the blue curve is the image of the yellow circle with respect to the map $z\to z^2+1$.